oauth 2.1 implement application password
I need to make API calls from scripts, from my own Oauth API (symfony league-php/oauth-server-bundle), on the behalf of an user.
I found out OAuth 2.1 deprecates the Resource Owner Password Grant (ROPG), and I would like to find a viable alternative.
In several applications, like in google, we can configure "application password", which are passwords used only to authenticate via the API, it doesn't expose the login/password.
In the rfc, they talk about the client_credentials flow, but it is not linked to a specific user.
Is there a flow in oauth 2.1 which could make possible to implement "application password" (on the behalf of a user) ?
Edit: I made a try with client_credentials auth
In my test I created a custom Oauth Client Entity in:
// App\Entity\Oauth2\Client
...
use League\Bundle\OAuth2ServerBundle\Model\AbstractClient;
...
#[ORM\Table('oauth2_client')
...
class Client extends AbstractClient
{
  ...
  #[ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity: User::class)]
  protected ?User $user = null;
  ...
}

With a custom command, I can create a row in oauth2_client with user_id defined.
Problem:
That solution makes the user of class League\Bundle\OAuth2ServerBundle\Security\User\NullUser, and not App\Entity\User, so I can't use security.yml access_control (which needs logged in user's roles).
I would like the user to be authenticated as if it was a password grant_type authentication. Are there ways to achieve this ?
Remark I'm able to retrieve the oauth2 client from the token from security.token_storage, manually.

This could be helpful: https://oauth2.thephpleague.com/authorization-server/which-grant/

@RonvanderHeijden Thanks for the link. I made the test with client_credentials, and edited the question to include what is blocking me.
